# R.exe, Rcmd.exe, Rscript.exe and Rterm.exe: what's the difference?

Tags: r, executable, rgui, rterm

I'm struggling with the different R executables. What is the difference between R.exe (with or without CMD BATCH option), Rcmd.exe, Rscript.exe and Rterm.exe when running command line in a batch file?

And what is the difference between:

```
R.exe --no-environ --no-save < "c:\temp\R\test.R" > "c:\temp\R\out.txt" 2>&1
```

and

```
R.exe CMD BATCH --no-environ --no-save "c:\temp\R\test.R" "c:\temp\R\out.txt"
```

No difference in the output.

I cannot find anything about Rcmd.exe and Rscript.exe in the 3079 pages R reference manual.

By the way: I am using Windows.

Comment: How about [R Introduction - Invoking R from the command line](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line)? And [two section later - scripting with R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scripting-with-R).

Comment: Yes, I've read that. But no word about Rcmd.exe and just a few lines about Rscript.exe. help(Rscript) gives me some more information

Comment: $R CMD BATCH  test.R out.Rout

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Caveat: I work *much* more on Linux than Windows:

- `Rcmd.exe` is a historical left-over as back in the day, you could not do `R CMD something` on Windows but needed the special executable `Rcmd.exe something`.  That is no longer the case, yet it is provided for backwards compatibility.
- `Rterm.exe` is also a holdover from the days when `Rcmd.exe` was used. Can be ignored these days.
- `R CMD BATCH` is a crutch that was needed in the days before [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/littler/index.html) and `Rscript.exe`, and similarly lingering from old docs and habits..
- `Rscript.exe` is your friend for batch scripts; use it.
- For everything else, there's `R.exe`.

Other than that, as Marek hinted, the reference manual is the wrong one among the six available manuals.  Try the *Introduction to R* and the *Installation and Admin* manuals both of which have specific appendices for Windows.

Comment: Thanks. So I can forget Rcmd.exe and R CMD BATCH?

Comment: I just want to run a R script with command line agurments in a Windows (shell) batchfile. As I understand it correctly R.exe is enough for me.

Comment: R Introduction states "Within a terminal window (...) invoking by R.exe or more directly by Rterm.exe". So for everything else Rterm?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about `Rterm.exe`. Also a leftover.

Comment: Remarkable: When I start R.exe with a R script by using a batchfile I see a R.exe process AND a Rterm.exe process running in the Windows Task Manager

Comment: There is an important difference between R.exe and Rterm.exe - Rterm.exe is compiled with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE and can allocate 4 GB RAM when run under Windows 64 bit, unlike R.exe (we're talking about 32 bit R running under 64 bit Windows). Why would the R people do this only for Rterm.exe and not for R.exe, if Rterm.exe is obsolete?

Comment: I can't know why they did it.  I know sometimes the smaller package is also faster.

Comment: ... also an important difference between R and Rscript in that Rscript does not load `package:methods` ... and that is part of why it is your friend for batch scripts (faster start up time) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680462/rscript-does-not-load-methods-package-r-does-why-and-what-are-the-consequen

Comment: And I demonstrated repeatedly that `r` starts faster than `Rscript` -- while *also* loading package `methods`.

Comment: The advice given here should be in the R and RStudio documentation.  `Rscript.exe` is your friend for batch scripts; use it.  For everything else, there's `R.exe`.  The R and RStudio documentation is not very helpful for Windows users.  R and RStudio are still very much written for the Unix / Linux / Mac OSX community.  They need to point out up front what are the leftovers in the Windows R and RStudio distros from ancient Unix and DOS days.

Comment: Thanks for that lovely explanation.  Does anyone know what purpose Rgui.exe serves?  Calling it from VBA seems to open the R GUI (outside of RStudio), but doesn't run the desired R script.