# Rterm.exe and Rcmd.exe

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me what does Rterm.exe and Rcmd.exe do.

Thanks,

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the explanations to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe) help?