# running R from windows command prompt

Tags: windows, r, platform

I have a R program in a txt file say `"functions.txt"`.
I load the `"functions.txt"` file the R using `source("function.txt")` 
 and then call functions `f1()`, `f2()` etc. which are declared and defined within
 `"function.txt"` file.
I also need to load a couple of R libraries using `library()` before I can use `f1()`, `f2()` etc.

My question is can I acheive all this (i.e. calling function `f1()` and `f2()`) from the windows prompt without opening the R environment ?

So essentially I want to

1. load the R libraries I need to run `f1()`, `f2()` etc.
2. load the `function.txt` file
3. run the individual functions f1() etc.
4. record the result

all from from the command promt of windows `c:\>`

I have windows version of R installed in my computers.
 It would be very kind of anyone to give a detailed answer as I am not very computer savvy.

Regards

Comment: Rscript.exe is your friend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe

Answer (score 24):

Bart's post is correct, but this can be done simpler. If the code

```
f1 <- function() {
  print("A")
}

f2 <- function() {
  print("B")
}

f1()
f2()
```

is in a file 'myRcode.R'; then

```
Rscript myRcode.R
```

will load and execute it, including the two function calls.

`Rscript.exe` is in the same directory as `R.exe` -- which one may have to add to the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 9):

The following "works on my machine" (not Windows though, but it should...):

If your `functions.txt` looks like:

```
f1 <- function()
{
  print("A")
}

f2 <- function()
{
  print("B")
}
```

the command:

```
Rscript -e "source('functions.txt');f1();f2()" > out.txt
```

should create the file `out.txt` containing:

```
[1] "A"
[1] "B"
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. A couple of more things 1> where do I find Rscript ? when I tried in my computer I got the message --'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. and also how do i load the libraries ?

Comment: Look in the installation directory of R (probably somewhere in `C:\program Files\...`). If you want to be able to run this `Rscript` executable from anywhere on your computer, you should add the directory it is in to your systems PATH variable (see: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a command line script, based on code above:

```
d:\misc2\bin\Rscript.exe    d:\r_code\mycode.r
```

Using Windows 7, I ran it as a .bat file.  Works fine.  Thanks for the tip.  (of course, these are just my particular subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

Add the R bin directory to PATH (windows Enviromwntal variables)

- This PC > Properties > Advanced system settings > Enviromental Variables > select Path > Edit > Add the path to R bin > save

Run command prompt, then you can use either the "R" command to start a new R session in cmd, or "Rscript" to run a script (file)