# Is there any way to running R code on command prompt widows?

Tags: windows, command, prompt, rscript

Please help. I want to run myRcode.R on command prompt windows 8. Therefore I tried to use Rscrip.exe. I changed the name of my file to Rscript myRcode.R but command prompt showed an error: “Rscript not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file."
I added C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64 to the environment variables in **path**. But command prompt showed a new error: “cannot open file “myRcode.R”: no such file or directory. 
I studied many command in this site about this problem, but I could not to use them after two weeks. I am not a professional user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running R from windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720317/running-r-from-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: You might need to verify that R is in that directory. Try running `C:\"Program Files"\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe` by itself from a command window. You should get a usage message if it's there.

Comment: I do it from a command window :usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args].....

'file' may contain spaces but not shell metacharacters
Expressions (one or more '-e <expr>') may be used *instead* of 'file'
See also  ?Rscript  from within R.                                       Is it correct?

Comment: Are you running it from the same directory where you saved your script? `C:\"Program Files"\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe myRcode.R`

Comment: No.in fact.I am using a software which it running on command prompt windows. In the part of running, it tries to invoke the system or console command with an external file. I use myRcode.R as external file. But myRcode.R is opened in Rstudio environment without running it. Actually, myRcode.R is not an executable file. myRcode.R is located in software folder.

Comment: I tested. The file is located inside C:\"Program Files"\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe myRcode.R 
Unfortunately, 
“Cannot open file “myRcode.R”: no such file or directory.

Comment: Ok, in your command prompt window you need to be in the same directory with myRcode.R, or R won't be able to find it. Otherwise, you can specify the path by running `C:\"Program Files"\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe C:\RStudio\Directory\Path\To\myRcode.R` (replacing that last bit with your actual path to your script).

Comment: C:\XX\Rscript myRcode.R-
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\ Rscript.exe-
C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\x64-  
XX is a software which it running on command prompt windows. I added C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\ Rscript.exe to path. Please explain again. I did not understand.

Comment: Does running `Rscript.exe` by itself (no path, no `myScript` file) on the command line give you the usage message?

Comment: when i run Rscript.exe on the command line:it says 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' I do not know why? it is an environment variables.

Comment: In your system PATH variable, it should just be `C:\"Program Files"\R\R-3.3.3\bin\x64` without the script name (Rscript.exe). It only needs the directory where executable file is, not the file itself.

Comment: Ok.I was very thankful you are considering my problem.  I changed system PATH variable and then I ran Rscript.exe by itself.The message was similar to using path.  Furthermore, I tested Rscript myRcode.R by itself again and it showed an error: no such file or directory.

Comment: Ok, good. Now that your PATH is fixed, you should be able to run something like `Rscript.exe C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\myRcode.R` (replacing `xxx\yyy\zzz` with the actual path to your R script.

Comment: Alternatively, you can navigate to the directory where your script is (in your command window), then run `Rscript.exe myRcode.R`

Comment: Running software with Rscript myRcode.R, error: the system cannot find the path specified.
Running software with myRcode.R, it will open RStudio, but it does not run.
Both Rscript myRcode.R and myRcode.R are located in c:\XX and XX is software folder.
I cannot change place of my R code file because software will show:  no such file or directory

Comment: In XX software, I can only write the name of my file. Only one name for a file.

Comment: If you have a file named "Rscript myRcode.R" you shouldn't. It should just be "myRcode.R". Rscript is the name of the executable file that then parses and runs your code. Try running `Rscript.exe myRcode.R`

Comment: Unfortunately. It does not work. Error message text: no such file or directory.

Comment: I am delighted to inform you that I used Rscript "c:\XX\y.R" and it worked. How to sum up Rscript "c:\XX\y.R” to a name?
I added Rscript "c:\XX to environment variables but it did not work. I want to running “y.R “

Comment: It takes a lot of additional setup to do that, but you can read how here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/ If you only have a couple of scripts that you want to run this way, I'd probably stick with manually running them through Rscript.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your wisdom with me.I have seen it before. When I removed Rstudio, .Rexec was correct. When I use Rstudio
.Rexec is not executable R script file and for example y.Rexec will be opened in Rstudio environment.I am grateful for the positive learning environment you provided me with.

Comment: Bill the Lizard,  Thank you for your guidance and support.http://stackmirror.cn/page/s12ukg136l2s, Solved my last  problem.