# running R script from batch file

Tags: r, batch-file

I wrote a small R script that calaulate some calculation and make a csv file (by using write.csv) and it's work fine when running the script. Now I want this script run from .bat file, what i have to wrote in the .bat file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720968/5316882

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rscript` which is in the same folder as R.

Usage: `Rscript myfilename.R`

Comment: My batch file is- "R CMD BATCH "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\R.exe
"C:\RStudio\DailyRets\Dailyrets.r" 
sowhat i have to change?

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\RStudio\DailyRets\Dailyrets.r" ` or add Rscript to your `path` and use `Rscript "C:\RStudio\DailyRets\Dailyrets.r" ` https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: Hi, when running a batch file contain this- "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\RStudio\DailyRets\Dailyrets.r" , thereis a message - the system cannot find. I'm confused, what i have to change now?