# Integrate R with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, r, asp.net-web-api, r.net

Requirement:

Invoke R script (on server) via C#, e.g. via webapi. Here restful endpoint receives parameter (e.g. via GET request) and results from R execution is returned (e.g. as JSON).

I am aware of this:

[How do I run a Python script from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c)

which could be adapted to work with R, see also:

[running R from windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720317/running-r-from-windows-command-prompt)

I am also aware of rdotnet:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=rdotnet

Just wondering, which is the recommended way of integrating R and .Net at this point in time?

Comment: Did anyone know the answer?

Comment: @user122222 someone suggested https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/index.html - need to have a look at this again myself ...