# How to Execute R Script from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: r, command-line, windows-10

I have the following added to my system path on Windows 10: `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\x64`

Then I tried running from cmd prompt ~:> `R myscript.R`

> ARGUMENT 'example_batch.R' **ignored**

It proceeded to an interactive session without any execution.

No idea how it seemed to work in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720968/5289570). I would prefer something this simple, as it is in Python.

The following works `R -e "source('myscript.R')"`

But I'll never remember this when I need it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "Rscript.exe". Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506007/running-r-code-from-command-line-windows).

Comment: can you show your myscript.R file

Comment: Don't call R.exe, call Rscript: `Rscript myscript.R`

Answer (score 1):

Lucas's solution gave me an error when run in Powershell/Windows termianl (which is now the default on Windows 11). It seems that when the executable dir is inside quotation marks (""), Powershell treats it as a string.

To execute Rscript.exe in Powershell, you need to add `&` before the dir

```
& "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\PATH\TO\SCRIPT.r"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is by executing `Rscript.exe` (it's installed with R.exe inside R directory).
You can do:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.0\bin\Rscript.exe" D:\path\to\yourRfile.r arg1 arg2 arg3
```

*The quotation marks ("") are necessary because dir name `Program Files` has space between it and Windows CMD wouldn't recognize it without quotation marks.*

If you don't want to write R path, you can put R Path to your windows PATH environment variable. This way you could run like:

```
Rscript.exe D:\path\to\yourRfile.r arg1 arg2 arg3
```

If you have doubts how to add R path to Windows PATH environment variable, you can follow [these instructions](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10) (they are for adding Java to PATH, but you can use for R, the idea is the same).