# how to change line length on Rterm.exe

Tags: r, cmd, rgui, rterm

I am using `R 2.15.2` on `windows XP`.

I was used to use `Rgui.exe` but it was lacking the UNIX standards I like to use like `CTRL+R <=>backward research` and `CTRL+U <=>erase line` ...

If I missed something please tell me !

Then I tried `Rterm.exe` (which looks identical to `R.exe` to me) which has all those nice features. I found how to tune it right clicking on the top of the window to set height-width (it is like tuning the window you get from `cmd.exe`).

The problem is that now I cannot see on the window more than `75` characters, with a `$` at the end: like this:

`R) ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp$`

Not sure if it is a `R` option of a `windows` one, but if I set `options("width"=180)` I can see `data.frame` on the full width of the window...

Not sure what is happening, can I modify this?

## We still do not know the answer to that one, so I guess 50 pts goes to Oscar de León... good for him to bad for me...

Comment: did you read the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference). it looks like Rterm.exe can be ignored these days.

Comment: Yes I red this post, but in WinXP Rgui.exe do not have the features I refered about (backward search via CTRL+R etc...)

Comment: Hey, thanks. Sorry we did not find any solution. I was thinking, as a far-fetch, have you considered using CygWin? That brings a load of other complications, though.

Comment: Hey Oscar, can't really use it, it's my workstation at work so no admin no nothing... Plus If I had the choice I would simply change the OS ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, it appears to be built in.

There used to be a problem with R when [trying to print long strings](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2000-January/009935.html). Apparently it was fixed first in Rterm and other versions of R before being fixed in Rgui.

When Rgui was fixed, possibly it was by a different means, since this issue can be fixed in Rgui but not other windows versions of R. You can change the width of the console for output both in [Rgui](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-November/042645.html) and (later) [Rterm](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-December/221567.html).

The prompt is another story. It is actually not the same as the output space, and thus is controlled with a different option; but, this only works for Rgui. To do it, set `pgcolumns=180` in the `Rconsole` file under `[R HOME]\etc\`. This modifies the width of the internal pager of the Rgui console, and effectively enables you to type up to 180 characters per input prompt.

Possibly there is a way to integrate that behavior into Rterm, and maybe [Duncan Murdoch](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-November/059257.html) can point you in the correct direction (or prove me completely wrong).

Comment: very nice comment !!! thank you very much for all this information... very helpfull

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what is being requested. If what is needed in `RTerm.exe` is to display the end of a long line (and position the cursor there), then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. You can go back to the beginning of a line with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>. One can go back and forth repeatedly as needed  until the line is use <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

The control character of `readline` seem to be active, for instance <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> scrolls back one command and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> brings up the "next" command from history if you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> too many times. (These are the same behavior as the <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down arrow</kbd> keys.) See [link](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) for other expected `readline` behaviors.

On my machine <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> (which should have been <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>) did not natively move forward or backward by words, but <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> did so on a line that exceeded the console width and had the $'s marking either the right or left extents as having further material to look consider.

If you want to wrap display lines, then you need to consider alternatives or additions to `readline`: [link](http://nileshk.com/2009/05/08/rlwrap.html), but that is an untested suggestion and merely the results of a search for:  "readline wrap display".

Comment: Hello, thanks, the whole question was to the number of characters displayed before the $ such that I can write loooooong lines on the console. See what I mean ?

Comment: No I do not see. You want character counts of non-visible portion of the line??? (You can write long lines to the console so I do not see a problem there.)

Comment: When I write a looooong line to an Rterm terminal, at some point a `$` sign appear, meaning that I achieved the maximal number of character on one line, and If I write further the begining of the line is not visible anymore.
If I write `abcd tttttttttttttttttttttt` at some point I get `abcd tttttttttttttttttttttt$` meaning the maximal number of character is reached then if I continue and would like to write "new" I will get `d ttttttttttttttttnew$` (start of line invisible)

Comment: As I said earlier. .... if you want to go to the end of a line that is being entered, type CTRL-e. You will then see the "$? switch over to the left side of the console and you will be able to see "$tttt....tttttend" on the display. If this is not what you were requesting then please try to say what you want to see. (Your description of what happens is not what happens on my machine. On my copy of Rterm 2.15 running in WinXP. typing input at the the right-hand side of a console will shift the `$` to the left side and allow you to see the right hand text.)

Comment: What I want to see is : the whole line without any `$` so `abcd ttttttttttttttttttttttttttnew` I do not want this `$` limitation.

Comment: You are choosing to use Rterm.exe, which is not a program that can be expected to offer any sort of GUI-like features. It is clearly oriented to sync with 'readline' as explained above. The Mac-R-GUI and the RStudio IDE do offer a wrap-around, multi-line display, so it is possible. You could try to see whether anyone has built a 'readline' replacement for Windows or UNIX that offers your desired feature set.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I opened another question that if solved would allow me to switch to `Rgui` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073114/how-can-i-set-rgui-exe-for-backward-search may be you'll have the answer

Answer (score 1):

The command should be `options(width = 180)` (without the quotes around `width`), but when you run Rterm in the Windows shell, it doesn't respect changes to this value; it just prints output as wide as the console.

The best way of working with R is (almost always) to use an IDE.  Try emacs + [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) or one of the many vim plugins ([R.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1048), [vim-R](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628), [VIM:r-plugin](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html)) if you want something UNIXy.

Comment: I am using vim-r-plugin, though the console vim-R-plugin uses is the one you select, in my case Rterm.exe (Jackson allowed on my demand), setting option(width=180) is just setting how R print things, not how many character are displayed when you type a command... (am I clear)

Comment: It sounds like the issue is either with the vim or the plugin or the shell, rather than with R.

Comment: Having done some testing, I'd agree with @statquant that the problem seems to be with Rterm.exe. setting `options(width = 180)` or similar makes Rterm print output (e.g. data frames, vectors, etc.) with the greater width. However, when typing a command at the `>` prompt, when you get to the ~80th column, the text moves to the left and shows `> $`, followed by the last 60 to 80 characters of what you've typed. When you then press <enter>, the first ~80 characters that you typed on the previous line are shown after the `> `, followed by a `$`, but the rest of the text is not shown.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing mate

Comment: RStudio also seems to respect the width option.