# How can I set Rgui.exe for backward search

Tags: r, cmd, rgui, rterm

If you use `Rterm.exe`, a nice feature is that:

> CTRL+R : backward search meaning CTRL+R+lib will show last command starting with lib like library(Rcpp)

`Rgui.exe` seems to lack this feature. Can I add it somehow ??
I use `Windows 7`, and changing is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Brian Ripley had to say about this request (albeit 6 years ago):

"https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-February/087540.html"

Comment: good, so I was right to use `Rterm.exe` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237467/how-to-change-line-length-on-rterm-exe but as you know I have a problem with it. About contributing, I am afraid this is well above my current skills else I would have commited the patch a long time ago...

Comment: I found that there are extensions to readline and put details in an edit to my answer on that other page