# R: Scheduling code in a webpage

Tags: r, web, markdown, schedule, r-rook-package

I'm trying to build a webpage displaying a few graphs. I want to use R to build the graphs, and I want these graphs to automatically update themselves periodically. For example, a webpage showing a graph of the stock price of a particular company over time, which refreshes every day with new data.

what is the best way to approach this? Using Rook to run the R-scripts? can I use it along Markdown, for example, to make the html webpage? Or do you suggest something else?

Comment: Perhaps you could submit a request to the authors of `shiny` to have a refresh timer implemented? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your plots in a R file and write your webpage in markdown in which you call your R objects and plots. Alternatively you can also run the R code directly in the markdown file. With the [`knit2html`](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/knitr/knit2html.html) function of the `knitr` package you can create the html page with the desired output. You can find basic examples on the `knitr` [webpage](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/).

You can schedule these file(s) on your own computer or on a server to update the data of the html output every day. If you have a machine that runs on Windows you can use the Windows Task Manager to run the batch file.

EDIT:

Here you can find a worked out [example](http://fishyoperations.com/r/creating-a-business-dashboards-in-r/).

Comment: I haven't worked with Windows Tasks Manager before and can't quite figure it out yet. I've made a *.bat file with the following lines:

"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\bin\i386\Rgui.exe"
R CMD BATCH "C:/../Rscript.R"

R opens, but the code doesn't run. when I place it all on the same line, it gives me that it ignored 'R', 'CMD' and 'BATCH'.

Comment: Try "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\..\Rscript.R" or  "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\..\Rscript.R"

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly fast reply! But I can't get to work. each time, R does open, but the code doesn't run. i've read that for the R script, the destination must use forward slashes instead of backslashes. My result stays the same though: after R opens, nothing happens.

Comment: I use the Rscript.exe version most of the time and use backslashes for the destination file, it works just fine. Here is some other information about R in batch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference