# R Command not recognized when submitted with SSH

Tags: linux, r, ssh

I am submitting a shell script on a remote host that in turn submits an R script, but the error `R: command not found` or `Rscript: command not found` (depending whether I tried `R CMD BATCH` or `Rscript`).

I have tried submitting in the following ways:

```
 ssh <remote-host> exec $HOME/test_script.sh

 ssh <remote-host> `sh $HOME/test_script.sh`
```

The script `test_script.sh` contains (have tried `Rscript` as well):

```
#!/bin/sh

Rscript --no-save --no-restore $HOME/greetme.R

exit 0
```

The script `greetme.R` contains only `cat("Hello\n")`.

The reason I am getting flustered is that when I log into the `remote-host` and submit the original script with `sh $HOME/test_script.sh`, it runs as intended.

The system specs and R versions for both the local and remote hosts are identical:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu    
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance
```

Why is Linux refusing to recognize the commands?

I would prefer solutions using `R CMD BATCH` or `Rscript` but if there are known workarounds using `littler` or `%R_TERM%` I would like to hear them too.

I used this related question as reference, as well as the documents referenced in the comments: [R.exe, Rcmd.exe, Rscript.exe and Rterm.exe: what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference)

**EDIT for solution:**

As @merlin2011 suggested, once I specified the full path in the `test_script.sh`, everything worked as intended:

```
#!/bin/sh

/opt/R/bin/Rscript --no-save --no-restore $HOME/greetme.R

exit 0
```

I got the path also by the provided suggestion:

```
$ which Rscript
/opt/R/bin/Rscript
```

Comment: Have you tried `R --slave -f script.R --args arg1 arg2 ..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you have a `PATH` issue, where `R` is not on your `PATH` when you try to run the command through `ssh`.

If you specify the full path to `R` and `Rscript` on the remote host, it should resolve the problem.

If you are not sure what the full path is, try logging into the server and running `which R` to get the path.