# R, RStudio: Programmatically switch between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of R

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a function that, within RStudio, restarts the R console in 64-bit mode or 32-bit mode without re-opening RStudio (or at least automatically re-opening it if that can't be avoided)?

I commonly run in 32-bit when using `RODBC` so that I can retrieve data from an Access database, but would like to otherwise leverage the capabilities of 64-bit mode for all other tasks while still in RStudio.

Comment: You could just call the other version with `system`, like: `system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/x64/R.exe"), wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)`, but maybe you could clarify exactly what you're hoping for.

Comment: That's a very slick function, @Thomas. Thanks for turning me on to the `system` function. Please see my clarified question. I'll check the Support section of RStudio as well.

Comment: @Thomas would you mind adding a bit of clarification on your comment.  If working in 64 bit RStudio but I want to temporarily change to 32 bit in order to connect to an RODBC Access Database using odbcConnect, how  how does the system function change from one (64 vs. 32 bit) to another.  Maybe post as an answer...?  Thanks!

Comment: @B.Davis, it opens another instance of R in which you could perform some operations, before returning to your normal RStudio session.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the part of your code that you wish to execute using the 32-bit executable into a new script. For example, I have a script called `myscript.r` which will just print which version of the R executable (64 or 32-bit) which was used to run it:

```
cat(as.character(version[2]))
```

Of course you could replace this with the part of your code dealing with `RODBC`.

Now the main way to programmatically run a script with a custom executable is to invoke a *command* to the OS *terminal* or *shell*. This command should contain:

- Which executable to invoke, in our case R 32-bit (the `Rscript.exe` file contained in the `i386` folder of your `R_HOME` directory)
- Arguments accepted by this executable, such as the path to the R script we want to run using this executable.

The path of `myscript` is `"c:/gp/trash/myscript.r"`, and my 32-bit R executable is

```
paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/i386/Rscript.exe)
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.4/bin/i386/Rscript.exe
```

I can run this script using:

```
myscript <- "c:/gp/trash/myscript.r"
output <- system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/x64/Rscript.exe ", myscript), wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE, intern = T)
output
[1] "x86_64"

output_32 <- system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/i386/Rscript.exe ", myscript), wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE, intern = T)
output_32
[1] "i386"
```

So as you can see we're executing this script from two different executables. In practice I'd suggest to save the results of your ODBC queries to a file, which you can read in your main `x64` R session.

---

Just a little vocabulary if you don't know some of these terms:

The terms terminal or shell are often used interchangeably. In RStudio, if you click on the *terminal* tab next to *console*, you'll be able to enter *commands* that will be processed by a *shell*.

- Shell *commands* are instructions that instruct the system to do some action.
- A *shell* is a user interface for accessing the services of an operating system.
- A *terminal* is a wrapper program that runs a shell and allows us to enter commands.

sources: [terminal, console and cli](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-terminal-console-shell-and-command-line/), [shell commands](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-shell-commands#:%7E:text=The%20shell%20is%20the%20command,system%20to%20do%20some%20action.), [scripting with r](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scripting-with-R), [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415135/5224236)