# Source R script using 32 bit R from 64 bit RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

On Win7 I have both 32 bit and 64 bit R installed. Because one can't ODBC to 32 bit MS Access from 64 bit R, I want to source an R script using the 32 bit version of R. From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881539/r-rstudio-programmatically-switch-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-r) I understand that I can launch 32 bit R using `system()` with

```
system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/i386/R.exe"), wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)
```

This launches R in a terminal. Is it also possible to source an R script from a `system()` call?

I wondered whether R CMD BATCH would be a possibility, but I can't see a way to set it to 32 bit R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to use `Rscript.exe` to run the file, rather than `R.exe`. You can do this by just using `/bin/i386/Rscript.exe your_rfile.R` - this is how I would execute R code from the command line in Windows.

Comment: As an addendum to this, it's possibly worth noting that if the file path of `your_rfile.R` has a space in it, then it will need shell quoting. The following should work:
`system(paste0(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "/bin/i386/R.exe ", sqQuote("C:\\path to\\file.R")), wait = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)`

Comment: @r.bot except `Rscript.exe` instead of `R.exe` and `shQuote` rather than `sqQuote`