# Run R script using batch file

Tags: r, batch-file

I'm attempting to schedule an R script as mentioned in 
[the Scheduling R Script stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script) but I keep getting an error that says

```
ARGUMENT 'BATCH' \__ignored__

ARGUEMENT 'C:/Users/cburton/AutomaticJobPuller/jobsPuller.R' \__ignored__
```

and then it has the startup prompt for the R programming environment.

The contents in my batch file are

```
C:\Users\cburton\Documents\R\R-3.2.0\bin\R.exe BATCH     C:\Users\cburton\AutomaticJobPuller\jobsPuller.R --vanilla
```

This is my first batch file, so I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't find the answer to this.

Comment: The answer you mentioned uses Rcmd.exe, not R.exe . I'm a Linux user, so I'm not sure, but may be worth a try (Rscript.exe too). See this one for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference

Comment: Have you tried `C:\Users\cburton\Documents\R\R-3.2.0\bin\Rscript.exe C:\Users\cburton\AutomaticJobPuller\jobsPuller.R --vanilla`?