# how to set command line parameter in RTerm (to use them with CommandArgs after source'ing a r file)

Tags: r, rterm

I'd like to debug RScripts. These scripts uses the commandArgs()-function to get some parameter.
Can i change/set these Parameter in a RTerm*-Session, just before i run "source(filexyz.r)"?

If thats not possible, is there another possibility to debug a r-file, without changing the script, but setting command line arguments?
I know i can set some vars in the variable explorer, but as far as i know, the commandline args aren't a part of this!?
Also i know i can start this script with 'rscript filexyz.r arg1 arg2 ...', but afaik i can't debug this session.

If it's helpful: I use VS2015 with 'R Tools for VS' and R-3.2.4revised.

*'RTerm' is a placeholder for every interactive R-shell, like RTerm.exe, R.exe (which calls RTerm.exe) and the interactive shells in VisualStudio (i think it's the Microsoft.R.Host.exe) and R Studio.

Comment: [Rterm.exe is also a holdover from the days when Rcmd.exe was used. Can be ignored these days.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3415135/680068)

Comment: Okay. 'RTerm' is a placeholder for every interactive R-shell, like RTerm.exe, R.exe (which calls RTerm.exe) and the interactive shells in VisualStudio (i think it's the Microsoft.R.Host.exe) and R Studio. I'll add this into the question.