# Why .bat file doesn't initiate R file

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

I would like to invoke R script by using a .bat file.
For testing, I saved an R file on the desktop in the name print_test.R
The code in this file is:

```
p<-500
write.csv(p,"print.csv")
```

I wrote the .bat file :

```
@echo off
R CMD BATCH C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R
```

UPDATE:
After adding pause to the .bat file I got the following text:

```
"'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . ."
```

When I click on the bat file (also saved on the desktop) there is a blink of the CMD window but the print.csv file is not created.What is wrong?

Comment: Try adding the location of your `R` installation before `CMD BATCH`

Comment: Maybe you have an error, put `pause` at the end of your bat file for see some output message.

Comment: something like `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R"` - change the `R-3.2.3` version accordingly

Comment: Have you tried to do it using `Rscript?` a lot of the more recent stuff is recommended using that instead of `CMD BATCH`

Comment: If `Rscript.exe` or `R.exe` is within your system path. `RScript C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R` should work.

Comment: I added an update inside my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the automated utility, *Rscript.exe*, as the `R CMD BATCH` might be considered a legacy command. See post: [R.exe, Rcmd.exe, Rscript.exe and Rterm.exe: what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference)

Rscript as an environment PATH variable:

```
@echo off
Rscript "C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R"
```

Rscript not as a environment PATH variable (where you specify full path of the executable -usually in bin folder of installation):

```
@echo off
"C:\Path\To\Rscript" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R"
```

OR if paths do not have spaces:

```
@echo off
C:\Path\To\Rscript C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed Sumedh's tip :
here is the new code:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\x64\r.exe" CMD BATCH  "C:\Users\User\Desktop\print_test.R"
```