# Running an R script from command line (to execute from python)

Tags: python, r, shell, command-line

I'm currently trying to run an R script from the command line (my end goal is to execute it as the last line of a python script).  I'm not sure what a batch file is, or how to make my R script 'executable'. Currently it is saved as a .R file.  It works when I run it from R.
How do I execute this from the windows command prompt line? Do i need to download something called Rscript.exe? Do I just save my R script as an .exe file? Please advise on the easiest way to achieve this.
R: version 3.3   python: version 3.x  os: windows

Comment: if it works when you click on the icon in the windows explorer, then a simple `os.system` would work, or a `subprocess.Popen` with the `shell=True` option set. Of course, creating an exe from your script would work right away with the 2 methods I just described, but it may be cumbersome in some test-and-modify phases of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already have R, since you can already run your script.

All you have to do is find its binaries (the Rscript.exe file).

Then open windows command line ([cmd] + [R] > type in : "cmd" > [enter])

Enter the full path to R.exe, followed by the full path to your script.

Comment: I have the program R.  I also am using a jupyter notebook to run python scripts.  could you please give an example of exactly what to type into the windows command prompt for me to run an r script?

Comment: it depends where RScript is.
First you have to find the binaries in your system, maybe make a search in your R Installation folder for Rscript.exe)

Comment: maybe though it's already in the PATH, so try just to type : Rscript.exe in the terminal

Comment: I get the output :
'Rscript.exe' is not recognizable as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
when i input:
Rscript.exe
into the windows command prompt. I assume it is not in the path but I'm not sure where it is. currently searching for it.

Comment: Maybe in R code editor's options you can have the full path to the interpretor.

Comment: thanks, I found where Rscript was and now can use --  Rscript.exe full\path\rfile.R in the command prompt

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, Rscript.exe the automated executable to run R scripts ships with any R installation (usually located in bin folder) and as [@Dirk Eddelbuettel mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference) is the recommended automated version. And in Python you can run **any** external program as a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) with various types including a *call*, *check_output*, *check_call*, or *Popen* and the latter of which provides more facility such as capturing errors in the child process.

If R directory is in your [PATH environmental variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them), you do not need to include full path to RScript.exe but just name of program, *Rscript*. And do note this is fairly the same process for Linux or Mac operating systems.

```
command = 'C:/R-3.3/bin/Rscript.exe'          # OR command = 'Rscript'
path2script = 'C:/Path/To/R/Script.R'
arg = '--vanilla'

# CHECK_CALL VERSION
retval = subprocess.check_call([command, arg, path2script], shell=True)

# CALL VERSION
retval = subprocess.call(["'Rscript' 'C:/Path/To/R/Script.R'"])

# POPEN VERSION (W/ CWD AND OUTPUT/ERROR CAPTURE)
curdir = 'C:/Path/To/R/Script'
p = subprocess.Popen(['Rscript', 'Script.R'], cwd=curdir,
                     stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr = subprocess.PIPE)            
output, error = p.communicate()

if p.returncode == 0:            
    print('R OUTPUT:\n {0}'.format(output.decode("utf-8")))
else:                
    print('R ERROR:\n {0}'.format(error.decode("utf-8")))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I tried the "CHECK_CALL VERSION" line and it says that my command returned a non-zero exit status 1.  When I ran Rscript.exe full\path\rfile.R in the command prompt it worked perfectly.  Note that my R script does not have any return line, it only edits a powerpoint presentation with the R2PPT/RDCOMClient packages.

Comment: Carefully check the paths. As commented, use `command = 'Rscript'` (.exe not needed) instead of full path as your command prompt indicates you have R in `PATH` variable. And because no output is returned, nothing on Python console should appear.

Answer (score 3):

You already have `Rscript`, it came with your version of R. If `R.exe`, `Rgui.exe`, ... are in your path, then so is `Rscript.exe`.

Your call from Python could just be `Rscript myFile.R`.  Rscript is much better than `R BATCH CMD ...` and other *very old and outdated* usage patterns.

Comment: could you elablorate please? do i need to import anything in python in order to do this? am i to use subprocess.Popen as mentioned above? could you give an exmaple of what to type in python

Comment: You need to adjust your PATH so that the notebook knows where the R binaries are.  The `popen()` and `system()` etc pp will all be able to call it ----- that is pretty much _exactly_ what PATH is for. How to adjust the PATH on Windows has been explained numerous times before.