# Can we create wordcloud by executing Rscript from the terminal

Tags: r, rscript

I'm developing an application where I need to create Wordcloud of twitter data and also some plots. I tried from RStudio. Now I need to develop a client server application which require all the Rscript to be executed from backend.

Is there any way to create a wordcloud from terminal and save it

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows, you could try the `Rscript.exe` executable.

See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference).

Comment: I'm using Linux

Comment: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/using-r-as-a-scripting-language-with-rscript.html