# Why does running shiny start two Rscript processes on windows when launching from cmd line?

Tags: r, cmd, shiny, shiny-server

When I start an `R` script that runs a `shiny` app from the `cmd` line, it appears to launch ***two*** instances of `Rscript.exe`? I can always kill the smaller of the two and the app continues to run? Can someone elaborate on what is actually going on behind the scenes or tell me what I am doing wrong that is creating double processes?

---

#### super_simple.R

```
require(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
  }
)

runApp(app, launch.browser = FALSE, port = 1234, host = "10.123.4.56")
```

Now if I launch this via the `cmd` line:

```
START Rscript --vanilla C:\Users\Jason\Projects\super_simple.R
```

At this point, I can point my browser to `http://10.123.4.56:1234` and see the app. However, if I look at my running processes via: `tasklist /FI "imagename eq rscript*"` I see ***two*** `Rscript.exe` processes:

[image: Processes]

What I've determined, however, is that I can always kill the smaller of the two (e.g., `taskkill /pid 9360 /f`) and yet the app still functions in its entirety? NOTE: I have tried starting the command in the background via `START \b ...` but the outcome is the same.

Comment: I guess one instance runs your script, and `runApp` creates a second instance just for the app itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general thing with the R scripting command-line utilities (`Rscript.exe`, `R.exe`, `Rcmd.exe`) and not specific to Shiny. All of these actually call `Rterm.exe` underneath to run the actual program in a separate process.

Try `Rscript.exe` with  `--verbose` and you'll see what I mean:

```
> Rscript --verbose script.R
running
  'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-34~1.0\bin\x64\Rterm.exe --slave --no-restore --file=script.R'
```

You can try out the other tools and see how they behave.

For more info, check out the source code

- https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/gnuwin32/front-ends
- https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/unix/Rscript.c

This question has some good info as well

- [R.exe, Rcmd.exe, Rscript.exe and Rterm.exe: what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference)