# Create powershell script to execute and generate a log file for R codes

Tags: r, powershell, logging

I'm quite new to this shell scripts. I have 4 scripts A10 to A40 written in R. Each file throws lots of messages in the interim. I want to write a script to execute all these 4 files sequentially and capture all the messages in a log file separately. The name of the log file should be `ABC-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.log`. It should not be overwritten next time when I execute the shell script. I searched in the google but couldn't find any document that could help me.

Comment: How are you currently invoking your scripts. By calling `rscript.exe`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to invoke the scripts.

Comment: Can you edit the R scripts? Rather than trying to capture all Powershell output in one file, it might be preferable to create the log file inside each R script using the `sink()` function, so you can easily distinguish the log for each script and choose whether you want to log messages, output or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following PowerShell script enumerating multiple `Rscript` command steps with all output (information, warnings, errors) redirected to a date-stamped log file. As information, Rscript.exe is the batch job executable, designed to run .R scripts at command line. See [R.exe, Rcmd.exe, Rscript.exe and Rterm.exe: what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3412911/1422451).

Below assumes you have the R installation *bin* folder (where `Rscript.exe` sits) in `Path` environment variable for PowerShell to recognize `Rscript`. Also `echo` commands are added to timestamp each R script run. Please adjust file names and paths as needed.

**PowerShell** *(save as .ps1)*

```
cd "C:\path\to\working\directory"

& {
    echo "`nExecution Start: $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

    echo "`nSTEP 1: R_A10_Script.R - $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
    Rscript Run_A10_Script.R

    echo "`nSTEP 2: Run_A20_Script.R - $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
    Rscript Run_A20_Script.R
    
    echo "`nSTEP 3: Run_A20_Script.R  - $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
    Rscript Run_A30_Script.R

    echo "`nSTEP 4: Run_A20_Script.R - $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
    Rscript Run_A40_Script.R
    
    echo "`nExecution End: $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

} 3>&1 2>&1 > "ABC-$(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-ss').log"
```

To run above script, simply call `PowerShell.exe` at command line, referencing .ps1 script with `-File` argument. In Windows Explorer, you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click on mouse/touchpad and select "Open PowerShell here" to launch PS terminal in any directory:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File RunRScripts.ps1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How to save this file? I mean using what extension?

Comment: See my [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73803802/revisions) explaining how to run the script.