# cmd window closes when running a R-Shiny App with a bat file

Tags: r, shiny

I have created an R shiny app that works perfectly when running in R studio. Now I want to be able to run it by just double-clicking on a bat-file, without starting R stuido. However, when I double-click on the bat-file, all that happens is that the cmd window opens and closes again, but the app is not opened in the browser.

My bat-file contains the following code:

```
"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/bin/R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('C:/Code/GUI', launch.browser = TRUE)"
```

Where `"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/bin/R.exe"` is the location where R is installed and `'C:/Code/GUI'` is the folder where the R shiny app and the bat-file are located.

Does someone know what I have to do to get it running?

*************Edit*************
After the suggestion from @Konrad Rudolph, I executed the commands from the .bat file by pasting them to the cmd window to see any error messages. Indeed, it seems like the commands themselves work fine, there is only a problem installing a package in the R script. However, this problem does not appear when running the code directly in R Studio. Any ideas why this is different when running the script in the command line and how to fix this?

Best regards
Nina

Comment: Do you get an error message when you place *pause* at the end of your batch file?

Comment: The reason that the command immediately closes again is probably due to an error in the command (e.g. incorrect path). I suggest opening a command window and executing the .bat file in there (rather than double-clicking it). That way, the window won’t close after execution, and you will be able to read any error messages that are created.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest utilizing `Rscript.exe` insted of `R.exe` which allows to pass the path of the script to run.

You could wrap your `runApp` call in a separate script e.g.:

*run.R (same folder):*

```
shiny::runApp(appDir = '.', port = 80L, launch.browser = TRUE, host = "127.0.0.1") # or host = "0.0.0.0" to make it available in the local network
```

and call it via *run.bat*:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\Code\GUI\run.R"
```

For further information please see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415135/9841389).

Comment: Unfortunately, both ways did not work. The command window still opens and then closes immediately.

Comment: @NinaK The above works fine on my system. Have you tried adding a **pause** command at the end of your batch file to see the error message?